# PHP/MySQL 403 Permission denied

Tags: php, html, mysql, hosting

I'm coming to you today with this question because I've been searching relentlessly to get this resolved, yet to no avail. From other topics that I've read it is likely a permissions issue on the web host, but I've actually tried this same code on a few different web hosts and get the same error on each of them, which is; "403 Permission denied"

Note: I've set the file permissions to "755" for all of the files on my host and I've also tested the dbcon.php file, it works fine.

The code that is throwing the error is the following

```html
<?php 

session_start();

require_once("dbcon.php");

if (checkVar($_SESSION['userid'])){
 
   $getRooms = "SELECT *
        FROM chat_rooms";
    $roomResults = mysql_query($getRooms);
}  

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Chat Rooms</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap"> 

 <div id="header">
 
     <h1><a href="/examples/Chat2/">Chat v2</a></h1>
     
     <div id="you"><span>Logged in as:</span> <?php echo $_SESSION['userid'] ?> (<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>)</div>
     
    </div>
    
 <div id="section">
 
        <div id="rooms">
         <h3>Rooms</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                    while($rooms = mysql_fetch_array($roomResults)):
                        $room = $rooms['name'];
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat_rooms` WHERE `name` = '$room' ") or die("Cannot find data". mysql_error());
                        $numOfUsers = $rooms['user_count'];
      // $numOfUsers = mysql_num_rows($query);
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="room/?name=<?php echo $rooms['name']?>"><?php echo $rooms['name'] . "<span>Users chatting: <strong>" . $numOfUsers . "</strong></span>" ?></a>
                </li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 403 can come from anywhere.. something inducing 403 on the `php` side or.. it could be the `.htaccess` perhaps explaining the structure of your project and related `.htaccess` might give a clue whoever want to help.

Comment: Check webserver logfiles

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess file as far as I can tell. As I said above, this happens on multiple hosts too.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing an important part of your while loop which is the closing part:  `endwhile;`

Although using alternative syntax is OK, I would recommend sticking to the traditional way of doing it with braces braces `{ }`.

Because I can't do further testing, you might find more errors. But for starters you need ti fix the missing `endwhile;`  or replace it with opening and closing braces `{ }`